# C# Appendtext in a loop

Tags: c#

I have to write a program that asks to user to specify a filepath location for a text file, which I did.

Then I want it to write a specified amount of random numbers on that same file that I just created.

Thus saving the the those random numbers in a text.
All this in one click event.

```
for (int count =userAmountNumber; count <=userAmountNumber; count++) 
{ 
    //Crates a random number 1-100 
    Random newRandomNumber = new Random(); 

    //creating and object with Random called rand 
    randomNumber = newRandomNumber.Next(1, 100).ToString(); 

    //Use the file path specified by the user here make sure everytime it loops itapeends or writes to the file 
    outfile = File.AppendText(filepath);
    outfile.WriteLine(randomNumber); 
    outfile.Close(); 
}
```

This is the code I have so far. It writes the data of the random number variable, but it only writes it once. I think it replaces it, even though I'm using appendtext as my method. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you, please post your current implementation of opening and writing to the file?

Comment: Please post your code in the question, use the formatting tools provided by the editor and avoid posting codes in comments or as a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems in your code I see right away:

1. You write to the file inside the loop.
2. You initialize the instance of `Random` inside the loop.
3. Your loop only runs once since you start with `count =userAmountNumber` instead of `count = 0`.

Once you fix problem #1, you will be able to see why problem #2 is actually a problem.

**What is problem #1?**
Your current implementation uses much more IO then it needs to.
You are opening, writing to and closing the file in each iteration of the loop.

**How to fix it?**
Instead of appending the text to the file inside a loop, you better append on the text into a buffer in memory, and only once the loop is over, write all the content of that buffer to the file.
The .Net framework provides a great buffer for strings called `StringBulider` - use that to store the string representation of the random number, and write all the string builder content to the file once the loop is done.

**What is problem #2?**
Once you fix problem #1, Your loop will run a lot faster. In fact, it will run so fast, you will see the content of the file contains the same number for multiple consecutive rows.
That's because you initialize the instance of `Random` inside the loop.
The `Random` class generates pseudo random numbers based on the seed it gets in it's constructor. If no seed was provided, it uses the current system time as a seed. When using the same seed, it will provide the same sequence of pseudo random numbers - so you will get the same number over and over again until the system time changes enough to change the seed of the `Random` instance.
**How to fix it?**
Simply instantiate the `Random` instance before the loop.

**Enough talk, let's see some code!**

```
// rnd is kinda the de-facto standard name for instances of the Random class
var rnd = new Random();             
// Same for sb and StringBuilder
var sb = new StringBulider();
// And the same for i and for loops...
for (int i = 0; i < userAmountNumber; i++) 
{ 
    // Appends the string representation of the next random number to the string builder
    sb.AppendLine(rnd.Next(1, 100).ToString());
}
// Appends all the content of the string builder to the text file.
// If the file does not exists, creates it.
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(filepath, sb.ToString());
```

As a bonus, using the `AppendAllText` method save you the trouble of dealing with file streams - it encapsulate all that plumbing code inside.

Comment: I use random inside the loop because I need a user specified amount of random numbers saved into a text file. How do I use a buffer to save my numbers?

Comment: From what I understand the user should specify the amount of numbers saved into the file - so the only you should take from the user is the `userAmountNumber` variable

Comment: Reviewing the code again I've found the reason why you get only a single row in the text file. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The code worked fine without using the stringBuilder as you suggested, In fact the loop was set to to the user specified number. (doi) =p As you suggested I fixed the loop to start at 0. Everything else works fine! In the Future I will keep your stringbuilder method in mind! :)

Comment: Oh I'm sure it works without the stringBuilder, however the computer running it works harder since you are putting all this pressure on the IO. Using my suggestion would make the code run faster and take less resources.